# Why it keeps on telling me "variable card might not have been initialized"

Tags: constructor

This is a java poker game project. At the beginning, I defined the Card class.

```
class Card {

/* constant suits and ranks */
static final String[] Suit = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
static final String[] Rank = {"","A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

/* Data field of a card: rank and suit */
private int cardRank;  /* values: 1-13 (see Rank[] above) */
private int cardSuit;  /* values: 0-3  (see Suit[] above) */

/* Constructor to create a card */
/* throw MyPlayingCardException if rank or suit is invalid */
public Card(int rank, int suit) throws MyPlayingCardException { 
if ((rank < 1) || (rank > 13))
    throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid rank:"+rank);
else
        cardRank = rank;
if ((suit < 0) || (suit > 3))
    throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid suit:"+suit);
else
        cardSuit = suit;
}

/* Accessor and toString */
/* You may impelemnt equals(), but it will not be used */
public int getRank() { return cardRank; }
public int getSuit() { return cardSuit; }
public String toString() { return Rank[cardRank] + " " + Suit[cardSuit]; }
```

Then, I tried to define Deck class to hold the Card. But I get problem in the Deck constructor. It keeps on telling me "variable card may not be initialized". I think I have already initialized it at the beginning of the constructor. What gives me error?

```
class Decks {

/* this is used to keep track of original n*52 cards */
private List<Card> originalDecks;   

/* this starts with n*52 cards deck from original deck   */
/* it is used to keep track of remaining cards to deal */
/* see reset(): it resets dealDecks to a full deck      */
private List<Card> dealDecks;

/* number of decks in this object */
private int numberDecks;


/**
 * Constructor: Creates default one deck of 52 playing cards in originalDecks and
 *          copy them to dealDecks.
 *              initialize numberDecks=n
 * Note: You need to catch MyPlayingCardException from Card constructor
 *       Use ArrayList for both originalDecks & dealDecks
 */
public Decks()
{
    // implement this method!

    ArrayList<Card> originalDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);
    ArrayList<Card> dealDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52); 

    Card card;
    for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)  {

        for (int j=1; j<= 13; j++)  {

            try{
                card = new Card(j,i);   
                }catch (MyPlayingCardException e){  
                    System.out.println("MyPlayingCardException: "+e.getMessage());
                }
            originalDecks.add(card); 
            }               
        }

    dealDecks.addAll(originalDecks); 


}

/**
 * Constructor: Creates n decks (52 cards each deck) of playing cards in
 *              originalDecks and copy them to dealDecks.
 *              initialize numberDecks=n
 * Note: You need to catch MyPlayingCardException from Card constructor
 *       Use ArrayList for both originalDecks & dealDecks
 */
public Decks(int n)
{
    int numberDecks=n ; 
    Card card; 

    for (int m=0; m<n; m++){

        for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) { 

            for (int j=0; j<= 13; j++)  {

                try{
                    card = new Card(j,i);      
                    }
                    catch (MyPlayingCardException e){   
                        System.out.println("MyPlayingCardException: "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                originalDecks.add(card); 
             }
             dealDecks.addAll(originalDecks); 
        }
    }             

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about this line ...

```
            originalDecks.add(card);
```

... and it is correct.

If the `Card` constructor throws a `MyPlayingCardException` then when you first try to initialize the `card` variable, then control will pass to the `catch` block *without `card` having been initialized*.  The `catch` block prints a message, but then just allows control to fall through to the line in question.  You can catch the exception and print a message, but in that case the catch block must also throw an exception (whether the same or a different one), or else it must somehow initialize `card` itself.

Note, too, that if the `Card` constructor throws a `MyPlayingCardException` on subsequent iterations of the inner loop then `card` will retain its previous value.  Although in that case it is not left uninitialized, the value it has is not one you actually want to use at that point.

Comment: Moved the originalDecks.add(card) to the try block. That fixed the problem.